# In Tumblr, how to remove vertical gap in masonry and make infinite scrolling work with it??

Tags: jquery

It is my first using stackoverflow. The following problem drove me insane for past few days. I really hope to find some help from here.

I am currently creating my own Tumblr Theme. I am using Masonry and today I got it work with infinite scroll. But I encounter following problems.

my Tumblr site is http://bojagicollection.tumblr.com/ I am using chrome.

1. there is a vertical gap between images and a small portion of image is placed on the top of next image. I set no margin nor padding. However I gave each container percentage width(25%)... I really want to get rid of white space and arrange them in an accurate manner.
2. Regarding contents show up after I scroll down to the point where infinite scrolling kicks in. As you can see, I add hover effect on each container, however it only applies to the containers that are displaced in an initial page. The effect does not work on the containers that appear with infinite scrolling effect.. how can I add same effect to those?

your help will be much appreciated.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
{block:Description} <meta name="description" content="{MetaDescription}" /> {/block:Description}

<title>{block:TagPage}{Tag} - {/block:TagPage} {block:SearchPage}{lang:Search results for SearchQuery} - {/block:SearchPage}{block:PostSummary}{PostSummary} - {/block:PostSummary}{Title}</title>

<link rel="shortcut icon" href="{Favicon}"/>
<link rel="alternate" type="application/rss+xml" title="{Title} RSS" href="{RSS}"/>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://static.tumblr.com/fwamms6/ZFamvxw9s/reset.css" />


<style>

body {
    background-color: white;
    color: black;
    font-family: "arial"";
    font-size: 1em;
}

a {
    color: blue;
    text-decoration: none;
}
h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6 {
    font-weight: normal;
    letter-spacing: 0.1em;
    text-transform: uppercase;
}

p {
    color: black;
    font-size:1em;
}

ul {
    list-style: none;
    margin:0px;
}

li {
    display: block;
    margin-left:0px;
}

img {
    max-width:100%;
}




//layout//

#content {
    width:100%;
}


.container{
    width:25%;
    float:left;
    overflow:hidden;
    padding:0;
}
.caption {
      position: absolute;
      top: 0;
      left: 0;
      background-color:black;
      opacity:0.2;
      width: 100%;
      height: 100%;
}

.captiona {
      display:none;
      position: absolute;
      top: 0;
      left: 0;
}



</style>

</head>

<body>

    <header id="masthead">
        <img src="{PortraitURL-128}"/>
        <h1><a href="/" title="{lang:Home}">{Title}aab</a></h1>

    </header>


<div id="content">


    {block:Posts}
    <div class="container">
    <div class="caption">
        <ul>


        </ul>
    </div>

    <div class="captiona">
        <ul>

            <li>{LikeButton color="black"}</li>
            <li>{ReblogButton color="black"}</li>
             <li>{block:Caption}{Caption}{/block:Caption}</li>
            <li>{block:PostNotes}{PostNotes} {/block:PostNotes}</li>
            <li>{block:ContentSource}
    <a href="{SourceURL}">
    a
    </a>
{/block:ContentSource}</li>
        </ul>
    </div>

        {block:Photo}

            {LinkOpenTag}<img src="{PhotoURL-HighRes}" alt="{PhotoAlt}" />{LinkCloseTag}


        {/block:Photo}



     </div>
    {/block:Posts}
    {block:Pagination}

        <nav class="pagination">
           {block:PreviousPage}<a href="{PreviousPage}">Previous page</a>{/block:PreviousPage}
           {block:NextPage}<a href="{NextPage}">Next page</a>{/block:NextPage}
        </nav>
        {/block:Pagination}
</div>



<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://static.tumblr.com/fwamms6/W8tmvy2eq/imagesloaded.pkgd.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://static.tumblr.com/fwamms6/F9lmvy2fb/masonry.pkgd.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://static.tumblr.com/fwamms6/WZfmvy2gd/jquery.infinitescroll.min.js"></script>


<script type="text/javascript">
$(function(){
var container = $('#content');

container.imagesLoaded( function(){
    container.masonry({
        itemSelector : '.container'
    });
});

container.infinitescroll({
      navSelector  : '.pagination',    
      nextSelector : '.pagination a',
      itemSelector : '.container',
      loading: {
          finishedMsg: 'No more pages to load.',
          img: 'http://i.imgur.com/6RMhx.gif'
        }
      },
      function( newElements ) {
        var $newElems = $( newElements ).css({ opacity: 0 });
        $newElems.imagesLoaded(function(){
          $newElems.animate({ opacity: 1 });
          container.masonry( 'appended', $newElems, true ); 
        });
      }
    );
});
</script>

<script type="text/javascript">
        $(window).load(function () {
$('#content').masonry({
itemSelector : ".container",
},
function() { $('#content').masonry({ appendedContent: $(this) }); }
);
});
    </script>


<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.container').hover(
            function(){
                $(this).find('.caption').fadeOut(250);
            },
            function(){
                $(this).find('.caption').fadeIn(250);
            }
        );
  });

</script>

<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.container').hover(
            function(){
                $(this).find('.captiona').fadeIn(250);
            },
            function(){
                $(this).find('.captiona').fadeOut(250);
            }
        );
  });

</script>




</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I don't know Masonry, but after examining the markup with the Chrome developer window, it looks like the white space problem is with the `<div>` tags themselves. They appear to be about 3px too low, which is creating that gap. For example, the blue one on the second row should be `top: 476px` rather than `top:479px`. Also, regarding the hover issue, basically I believe you need to reapply the `.hover` like you do in the `.ready` function. I'm guess you simply need to extract that bit into a separate function and call it from `imagesLoaded`.

Comment: Thanks @Teeg, however, I miserably failed to accomplish the look that I want... I got rid of vertical space by add 'margin-bottom:-3px', but couldnot solve the images are being overlapped. Also, couldnot quite understand what your suggestion for the hover issue. I am sorry for my lack of Java knowledge. it would be so much appreciated, if you can explain with code. Thanks~!

Comment: @Teeg  Tumblr blogger, BuildThemes helped me with getting rid of vertical gap. img{vertical-align: middle} works great.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you requested, here's how you can fix the hover issue. Keep in mind I don't know this Masonry library, so anything I wrote regarding that might be incorrect; you'll have to tell me whether its right.

First thing, I believe it will make things easier if you place everything in the same `<script>` tag, as opposed to individual script blocks.

As I said earlier, the problem is that your on hover function (`.hover`), is only applied when the DOM first loads, which obviously does not affect anything loaded after. From the code you posted, I'm assuming you'll also need to call that `.hover` code from the `$newElems.imagesLoaded`. Probably the easiest way to do that is to extract the `.hover` stuff out in to its own function and place it near the top of the script block, like so:

```
// this function takes a jQuery object
var handleOnHover = function($elements){
    $elements.hover(
        function(){
            $(this).find('.caption').fadeOut(250);
        },
        function(){
            $(this).find('.caption').fadeIn(250);
        }
    );
}
```

Which you can call from both your on ready function, AND the `imagesLoaded` function, like so:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var $container = $('.container');
    handleOnHover($container); // <-- Here
});

container.infinitescroll({
    navSelector  : '.pagination',    
    nextSelector : '.pagination a',
    itemSelector : '.container',
    loading: {
        finishedMsg: 'No more pages to load.',
        img: 'http://i.imgur.com/6RMhx.gif'
    }
},
function( newElements ) {
    var $newElems = $( newElements ).css({ opacity: 0 });

    $newElems.imagesLoaded(function(){
        handleOnOver($newElems); <-- here again

        $newElems.animate({ opacity: 1 });
        container.masonry( 'appended', $newElems, true ); 
    });
});
```

Comment: Thank you so much! Teeg! you are truly amazing! Now I can easily apply infinite scrolling to my Tumblr themes. Once again, thanks Tegg!!